# Webservice: How do I setup user directories to be available under /u/USER_ID

Tags: php, web, apache2, profile

I'm designing a small web service which does make use of user profiles.

Now, I want the specific user profiles to be available under  **domain.tld/u/USERID** (/u/USER_ID/index.php to be specific)

The naiive way to do this would be to make a directory for each user. However, there has to be another solution as many grand scale sites use a similar structure.

**Instead**: I want to use *one* index.php, I actually update with the user information of the requested profile.

I've only started working on web hosting / php with this project.

I'm assuming this is a problem I need to address using the web server config? I'm running apache2 currently.